# Gradle Issue in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin

Extracted the **android** package from ionic project, opened it in Android Studio,

**Distribution URL** : https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4-all.zip

**Inside Project level build.gradle** : classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4'

**Inside cash.properties :** gradle.version=7.4

Getting below error in Android Studio :

> 

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.4/gradle-7.4.pom
> - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.4/gradle-7.4.pom
> Required by:
> project :

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 746ms

What might be the Issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what i've seen [here](https://maven.google.com/web/index.html?q=gradle#com.android.tools.build:gradle), version 7.4 is not yet available on Google maven repositories.

You could try targeting a lower version (like 7.3.0-alpha05, or 7.1.2 if you need stable release), and don't forget to set the same version to your distributionUrl.

Comment: Changed it to 7.1.1 everywhere and still its showing : 
ailed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.version-check'.
   > Minimum supported Gradle version is 7.2. Current version is 6.8. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in /home/jaiminmodi/Documents/ionic/android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-7.2-all.zip

Comment: Try setting 7.1.2 in your build.gradle and let gradle-7.2-bin.zip in your distributionUrl, it's working for me

Comment: Plugin with id 'com.github.dcendentdroid-mas.anven' not found.

Comment: that's a different error, so i think problem is solved. You can create another SO question and send me link, maybe i could help for this one too. Don't forget to mark as answered if it was the solution, thanks !